# Wordpress ajax search get post category

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm using a wp theme which comes with an ajax search feature to get live suggestions. However the suggestion element displays the post type (under the resulted title) such as "Portfolio item" and I would like to replace it with the post (portfolio item's) category. Any solution? Thanks in advance!

```
   $suggestions=array();  

    global $post;  
    foreach ($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post);  
        // Initialise suggestion array  
        $suggestion = array();  
        $suggestion['label'] = esc_html($post->post_title);  
        $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();  
        $suggestion['image'] = (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) ? get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', array('title' => '')) : '<i class="icon-salient-pencil"></i>' ; 

        if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'post'){

            $suggestion['post_type'] = __('Story',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); 

        } else if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'page'){

            $suggestion['post_type'] = __('Page',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); 

        } else if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'portfolio'){

            $suggestion['post_type'] = __('Portfolio item',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); 

            //show custom thumbnail if in use
            $custom_thumbnail = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nectar_portfolio_custom_thumbnail', true); 
            if(!empty($custom_thumbnail) ){
                $attachment_id = pn_get_attachment_id_from_url($custom_thumbnail);
                $suggestion['image'] = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id,'portfolio-widget');
            }

        } else if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'product'){

            $suggestion['post_type'] = __('Product',NECTAR_THEME_NAME); 
        }
```